# NPM installation Error in windows

Tags: node.js, configuration, npm, msbuild

My nodejs recently got corrupt and re-installed. Now, i am facing this error while installing npm dependencies. What am i missing?

```
C:\Projects\xyz>npm i
/
> bufferutil@1.2.1 install C:\Projects\basic-vplex-sizer-ui\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Projects\basic-vplex-sizer-ui\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\ham13\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v4.4.3\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(57,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for v120 (Platform Toolset = 'v120') cannot be found. To build using the v120 build tools, please install v120 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Projects\basic-vplex-sizer-ui\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
```

More info:
[image]

Comment: For future reference. Copying the error message out and placing it in the text makes it easier for other peaple to find your question when searching for the same error :)

Answer (score 0):

If `Node.js` version has been changed, check with `node -v`  then you have to do [npm rebuild](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/rebuild)  if still getting the error then delete `node_modules` folder and do `npm install`.

Hope that works.

Comment: I removed nodejs, cleared all cache. Installed visual studio as well. Set the msvs path globally from npm. I have installed node-gyp globally. Still error exists